# Representations and subgroups of the translation group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, abelian-groups

Let $H_\lambda=\lambda\mathbb{Z}$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ be a subgroup of the 1-dimensional translation group $T$. Consider then the factor group  $K_{\lambda}=T/H_{\lambda}$ with representation $U_{\lambda}(x)$  for $x\in K_{\lambda}$. Then are the following two points correct:

1) $\exists$ a mapping $x'\in T \rightarrow x=x'H_\lambda \in K_\lambda$, which is in general many-to-one. $U_\lambda$ is also a representation of $T$  but a **degenerate** one.

2)  Can $\lambda$ be interpreted as the **wavelength** of a wave and $U_{\lambda}(x)=e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} x}$?

Comment: Is it better now?